# Updating state in react-native taking forever

Tags: javascript, react-native

I added the ability to 'like' a post.
And suddenly react-native is crawling at a snails pace.
Im new to react so aren't really sure where and when to properly set state.

How should I properly attach the ability to like a row, in a listView table??

Heres the code...

The 'like' text to click on is this....

```
 <Text onPress={this.likePost.bind(this, feeditem.post_id)}>{feeditem.likes} likes</Text>
```

Then the 'liking' function is this...

```
likePost(id){
  if(this.state.feedData!=null){
    var d = this.state.feedData;
    // Find row by post_id
    var ix = d.findIndex(x => x.post_id===id);
    // Only set state if user hasn't already liked
    if(d[ix].you_liked==0){

      // Mark as liked, and increment
      d[ix].you_liked=true;
      d[ix].likes = parseInt(d[ix].likes)++;

      // Set the state after liking
      this.setState({
        feedData: d,
        feedList: this.state.feedList.cloneWithRows(d)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

It works, and it properly updates the data, and shows in the dev tools just fine.  However, the rendering of the new state visually is taking over a minute.

Am I updating the state wrong?
What is the cost for setState? I thought react was supposed to just re-render the changes it sees in the virtual DOM.  Why then does it seem like its rerendering my entire listView.  And why over 1 minute load time??
(obvious memory leak somewhere)??

Also, is it possible to just increment the integer on the 'DOM' without triggering re-renders?

Answer (score 0):

Render your `ListView` passing `dataSource` and `renderRow` props

```
render() {
  return (
    <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow}/>
  );
}
```

Create `renderRow` function, where your can access your data and index of clicked row

```
_renderRow = (rowData, sectionIndex, rowIndex, highlightRow) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        //Here you shoud update state
    }}/>
  );
};
```

Furthermore, you always need to make copy of a state before manipulating it, because its immutable object. Try working with state mutating libraries, use https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html or other options.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but its not really my question.  Its my bad, because re-reading my question, I can see how you took it that way....But  I already know how to pass the row ID, and Im not even doing that in this case.  Im clicking on a text item, within a row.  Anyway....my question wasn't how to do it, it was how to do it so it doesnt take so long rendering. Your answer updates state in the same spot that Im updating it.  (in onPress function).  The question is why is the re-render dropping over 100 frames.  Also,am I not making a copy of state in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Animations can take a long time because of the chrome debugger.
A small way to mitigate this is using `InteractionManager`

```
likePost(id){
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    if(this.state.feedData!=null){
      var d = this.state.feedData;
      // Find row by post_id
      var ix = d.findIndex(x => x.post_id===id);
      // Only set state if user hasn't already liked
      if(d[ix].you_liked==0){

        // Mark as liked, and increment
        d[ix].you_liked=true;
        d[ix].likes = parseInt(d[ix].likes)++;

        // Set the state after liking
        this.setState({
          feedData: d,
          feedList: this.state.feedList.cloneWithRows(d)
        });
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Or disable chrome debugging and use android monitor to see debugging messages.

Comment: Hmm.... now its not even updating at all after putting this in there.  Also, am I correctly updating state??  Like am I doing it right?  By copying the previous state, then putting the new variable d in the old state place?

Comment: Oh yeah try wrapping your `Text` tag in a `TouchableHighlight` and moving the onPress to the `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: Its not that the touch event isnt working.  The function fires fine.  The data is updated in my array.  Its the actual setting of the state, so I can visually see the changes that is either  now not working, or taking forever.  So thats my real question.  How do I properly set state so that everything works.