# Why is ListView click handler executing functions on start

Tags: javascript, react-native

So Im using react-native, and it seems that when my app boots up it actually runs the functions attached to click handlers?  is this supposed to happen?
Or is this a bug??

I have:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>this._pressData(rowID)}></TouchableHighlight>
```

Then in the function I have:

```
this._pressData(theRow) { console.log(theRow); }
```

When I boot up my app, I just get a console log of numbers up to 1000.  If I put more logic in there, it wants to execute it all.

So for example if I put this in there,

```
this._pressData(theRow) { 
     this.setState({test: theRow});
     console.log(this.state.test);
}
```

the app takes extremely long to boot, because its literally running setState a thousand times, and console logging that.

How do I just get these functions to run only onPress.  and not at startup? (or is this a bug?)

(Finding this out, answers my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766641/how-to-properly-update-state-in-react-native)  on the issue.  That questions problem is clearly being caused by this same issue. )

Any ideas?

Im beginning to think I just have a broken build.  Maybe its time to downgrade lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code like this, using ES6 fat arrow:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressData(rowID)}></TouchableHighlight>
```

then declare your function this way

```
_pressData = (theRow) => { 
     this.setState({test: theRow});
     console.log(this.state.test);
}
```

Comment: yup, that worked. thanks! But howcome this code used to work, and now doesn't??

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to be a question of scope. Any answers would be appreciated though.